# Counting entries and pivot tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a question regarding pivot tables and summarizing

The source select statement output the following structure

```
Customer|ProductID
A       |1
A       |4
B       |3
C       |2
D       |3
D       |3
D       |4
```

I will like to convert this into a table with this structure:

```
Customer|Count|1|2|3|4
A       |2    |1|0|0|1
B       |1    |0|0|1|0
C       |1    |0|1|0|0
D       |3    |1|0|1|1
```

"Count" should be the number of products that the customer has bought, but I can't get it to work :(

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT customerId, CustomerNo, [1], [2], [3], [4] FROM

(SELECT id AS customerId, 
CustomerNo,
CASE ProductType
WHEN 1 THEN 1 /* Games */
WHEN 2 THEN 2 /* Cards */
WHEN 4 THEN 3 /* Gadgets */
WHEN 5 THEN 3 /* Accessories */
WHEN 6 THEN 4 /* Smartsphone acc. */
ELSE 255
END AS Products,
FROM
ProductSales
) AS SourceTable 

PIVOT ( 
COUNT(Products)
FOR Products IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable
```

This works fine, but I need to add some kind of COUNT in the first SELECT-statement in order to Count the number of records that each customer has.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

/Hans

Comment: Probably a typo but your data `D` doesnt have product `1`. And isnt clear if you want count product, Or just `0/1`, like `D` has two `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems doing it with PIVOT, based on your current query.
Just add the following column to the SELECT.

```
[1]+[2]+[3]+[4] as [Count]
```

---

Demo

```
create table t (customer char(1),ProductID int)
insert into t values ('A',1),('A',4),('B',3),('C',2),('D',3),('D',3),('D',4)
```

---

```
select      customer
           ,[1]+[2]+[3]+[4] as [Count]
           ,[1],[2],[3],[4]

from        t pivot (count(ProductID) for ProductID in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) t
```

> ```
> +----------+-------+---+---+---+---+
> | customer | Count | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> +----------+-------+---+---+---+---+
> | A        | 2     | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
> +----------+-------+---+---+---+---+
> | B        | 1     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
> +----------+-------+---+---+---+---+
> | C        | 1     | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
> +----------+-------+---+---+---+---+
> | D        | 3     | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
> +----------+-------+---+---+---+---+
> ```

Comment: I don't see any reason why was this answer downvoted, this is clearly the answer the @OP was looking for, +1 .

Answer (score 1):

Try with conditional aggregation instead of Pivot:

```
SELECT t.customerid,
       COUNT(*) as cnt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.productid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as first,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.productid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as second,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.productid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as third
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.customerid
```